# .net powerpoint application cant save

Tags: .net, office-interop, uac

I wasn't sure how to formulate my title so sorry if it wasn't clear enough :)

The purpose of my application (price offers) is quite simple:

- You write all client coordinates in a textbox
- The mail address will automaticly be retrieved from it
- All coordinates will be pasted in all the selected powerpoint templates (in the background)
- These will be saved in a pdf format (using **ApplicationPresentation.SaveAs(...SaveAsPdf)**)
- Where after they will be send through the .net mailing system.

Now Since the windows update the saving doesn't seem to be working anymore. I get an unknown com error (**Error -2147467259**). After some research I came across someone that had ***UAC issues***.

So I did some tryouts and indeed when I save my powerpoints to C:/ it works... The moment I try to get them on another drive it blocks and gives me an error.

Is there some configuration I need to do to a drive, to get it working?
My application worked though before the windows update. So there has been an override somehwere :(

Comment: Are you saving the ppt under a valid path where you have permissions to write? If you save the file under your user dir + AppData/ you can always save files.

Comment: Yes, Actually the drive I'm talking about is the Server drive which is set under drive Z... Now when I test the same program on a computer that hasn't internet access but is connected to our local server, it works. But still not on the updated computers

Comment: Sorry, where does come from the Error -2147467259? Is it wiindows? Or the debugger? If you can, put the SaveAs in a try/catch block and see if you get a more specific exception

Comment: thats from the debugger, no extra info is shown unfortunately.

Comment: did you try to save a file in same location using IO.File api?

Comment: okay so it seems the directory was renamed for some reason. Wasn't paying attention whether the first letter was capitalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fabio comment I managed to find a way to my problem so his comment was certainly usefull. As it seemed my problem was a renamed folder (just a capitalized letter) I didn't checked.